# Passport Node.js CORS error

Tags: javascript, express, cors, passport.js

I've tried a million ways to get passport to work with my application to no avail. Every attempted login to every provider (Facebook, Google, Twitter, Microsoft) has resulted in an error like this one:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=h…2F%2Ftest.sl%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Freturn&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.sl%2F. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://test.sl' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My application isn't that complicated, here's a summary of my server code.

```
var express = require('express');
var ppGoogle = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//There's more config

app.listen(7230);

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google'));
app.get('/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google', {
   successRedirect: '/main',
   failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

passport.use(new ppGoogle({
    clientID: '',
    clientSecret: '',
    callbackURL: 'http://test.sl/auth/google/return'
},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
{
    console.log('done');
}));
```

Anyone know the solution? This thing is driving me crazy.

Comment: Where is that error coming from? It shouldn't be doing that in the first place.

Comment: Sorry didn't specify, this is client-side with the browser that's trying to authenticate.

Comment: What's the stack trace making that AJAX request? What client code is doing that?

Comment: That's all automated by Passport. I don't know the details. The client is simply sending a GET request to /auth/google

Comment: That's wrong; you need to navigate to that URL, not AJAX-request it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I dunno why I thought it was a server error. Thanks so much. If you give an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to load Google's OAuth prompt over AJAX instead of a page navigation.

You should replace your AJAX request with a normal navigation,